# SQLite during select and insert

Tags: javascript, sqlite, select, insert

i have problem with SELECT and INSERT during a loop with SQLite.
Below my code:

```js
//This is an another function

var place=0; //Global variable
for(....){
        place++;
        insert();
}

function insert()   {

    db.transaction(function(sqls) {
        sqls.executeSql("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 LIKE '"+place+"'",[], function(tx,result){

            if(result.rows.length==0){
                 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO table1  (col1) VALUES ("'+place+'")',[],function(tx, result){  

                    col1=result.insertId;

                }, null);

            }else{
                //alert("Found, i will take the ID!");
                var len = result.rows.length, i;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    col1=result.rows.item(i).col1;
                    //alert(col1);
                }


            }
        }, null);
    }, errorDB, successDBConnection);
}
```

In this case, when i check if variable "place" is already in my DB the values inside this variable is only the last cicle of **for**.

So during my insert query, if the "place", on the last cicle, will have value "**50**" this is the value that will be insert in **col1**.

How  can i check and insert all 50 values?

Comment: "How can i check and insert all 50 values?" <- isn't this what you already do in your code? Are you asking if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: No, it fits me only the last value not all 50.